# Bluetooth not found after cloning SSD from a Windows & Linux dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, bluetooth, ssd

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and my Bluetooth has stopped working.
The situation is a bit complicated.
So, at first, I had this OS installed on an external SSD (I didn't think I would use it that much - only for work).
I used to boot from this external ssd on BOTH my Desktop (with no bluetooth) and on my laptop (Lenovo ThinkPad x230).
Then, I decided to clone this SSD with Ubuntu on my laptop's SSD (where I previously had Windows installed, but I decided I don't need it anymore).

After this cloning, some of my settings were not kept and the bluetooth has stopped working suddenly.

When I open the Bluetooth settings I get:
"No bluetooth found.
Plug in a dongle to use bluetooth."

I tried several solutions from the internet but none worked, including restarting the bluetooth from the BIOS.

Can anybody help me troubleshoot this problem, please?

Thanks.

Result of the command from the comments:

```
octavian@Octavian:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb; dmesg | grep -i blue
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville) [8086:1502] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville) [17aa:21f3]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1e2d] (rev 04)
--
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] [8086:0085] (rev 34)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 (802.11a/b/g/n) [8086:1311]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 147e:2020 Upek TouchChip Fingerprint Coprocessor (WBF advanced mode)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 04e8:6863 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd Galaxy series, misc. (tethering mode)
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Why don't you do a clean installation? If BT doesn't work, it will be much easier to solve. But now it is very unclear what you did. "Some of my settings were not kept" means that something was wrong.

Comment: @Pilot6 I have a lot of data and configuration files that would be lost and it would take me quite a while to get them again. That's why I chose to clone it in the first place. :)

Comment: How did you clone it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb; dmesg | grep -i blue` terminal command.

Comment: I don't see BT hardware. Is it enabled in BIOS?

Comment: @Pilot6 I cloned it on my desktop, on Windows. The external SSD (the source) was inside the computer, and the laptop's SSD (the destination) was in the external SSD tray, connected on USB on the desktop.

Comment: @Pilot6 it is, yes.

Comment: So how did you clone it? It is unclear at all. "On Windows" is not an answer. Anyway there is no BT hardware detected. It is unrelated to OS.

Comment: The `Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205` doesn't have an integrated BT device. And `lsusb` doesn't show it either.

Comment: @Pilot6 I used a software but I don't recall its name. About the Centrino, in bios there are two separate options for enabling/disablind the Wi-fi and the Bluetooth. So the bluetooth might be separated from it. You can check the laptop: lenovo thinkpad x230.

Comment: Try to boot form an Ubuntu LiveUSB and check if it works from there.

Comment: @Pilot6 by the way, it used to work before the cloning.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137868/discussion-between-octavian-niculescu-and-pilot6).

Comment: Cloning an Ubuntu disk using some unspecified Windows program is really a very bad idea. But it seems to be unrelated at all.

Comment: Can we talk on that link above? I'm really struggling with this and you might be able to help, if you want :)